# MongoDB on Raspberry Pi --dbpath not setting

Tags: mongodb, linux

I installed MongoDB using [this](http://c-mobberley.com/wordpress/2013/10/14/raspberry-pi-mongodb-installation-the-working-guide/) tutorial. I have tried to set `--dbpath` in `/etc/mongodb.conf` like this:

```
dbpath=/path/that/iwant

#where to log
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log

logappend=true
```

When I `mongod` I get:

```
ERROR: dbpath (/data/db/) does not exist.
```

Further more, if I declare `mongodb --dbpath /path/that/iwant` i get:

```
exception in initAndListen: 10309 Unable to create/open lock file
errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?
```

Q: How do I get `mongod` to reference the proper path in the config file without specifying.

Bonus: Why is permission being denied from mongo. (I have tried `sudo chmod -R 775 /path/that/iwant` and `sudo chown -R mongodb /path/that/iwant`)

I am new to mongo and database admin exchange. As a brother from Stack Overflow I am humbled.

Edit: I added the path `/data/db` to the pie and `chown mongodb` on it. If I `sudo mongod` the server starts. If I try to start it with my user it will not start getting an error `Unable to create/open lock file` which exists.

Edit: Here is what my `/etc/init.d/mongd` looks like:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON=/usr/bin/mongod
DESC=database

# Default defaults.  Can be overridden by the /etc/default/$NAME
NAME=mongodb
CONF=/etc/mongodb.conf
DATA=/path/that/iwant
LOGDIR=/var/log/mongodb
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
LOGFILE=$LOGDIR/$NAME.log  # Server logfile
ENABLE_MONGODB=yes
```

...further down

```
DAEMONUSER=${DAEMONUSER:-mongodb}
DAEMON_OPTS=${DAEMON_OPTS:-"--dbpath $DATA --logpath $LOGFILE run"}
DAEMON_OPTS="$DAEMON_OPTS --config $CONF --rest"
```

This is what `ps aux | grep mongo` looks like after i start the server with `sudo mongod`:

```
root     10747  0.1  0.3   5124  1612 pts/0    S+   10:41   0:00 sudo mongod
root     10748  1.8  3.8  84896 17416 pts/0    Sl+  10:41   0:00 mongod
1001     10823  0.0  0.1   3544   808 pts/1    S+   10:42   0:00 grep --color=auto mongo
```

Comment: I've had somewhat similar issues. First, /data/db is going to be the default data path. That's why it's trying to start there if you don't specify. You can specify in the init script. I don't see a note that you did that, and couldn't find an instruction in the tutorial you linked. Is $DATA specified there as called in this line? DAEMON_OPTS=${DAEMON_OPTS:-"--dbpath $DATA --logpath $LOGFILE run"}. Also, are you calling the init script when you start (e.g., service mongo start) to call in those values? Can you paste in your ps aux | grep mongo here when it's running?

Comment: I've edited my question and added that information @ValerieParham-Thompson. I thank you so much for the response. I thought I was a goner on this one.

Comment: OK. Are you typing "sudo mongod" or "sudo /etc/init.d/mongod start"?

Comment: @ValerieParham-Thompson I am typing "`sudo mongod`"

Comment: Ah, okay. Try using the init file... the instructions in that tutorial say "sudo /etc/init.d/mongod start" so that should be the right command. That should call in the variables you've specified in the init file, including the mongodb user. Does that work?

Comment: @ValerieParham-Thompson Oh wow, i get `[FAIL] Starting database: mongodb failed!`

Comment: That's not better, but that does seem to indicate it's reading the configs (and doesn't like them). What does the error log say? They are typically nicely verbose with mongo unless you've explicitly turned it down.

Comment: @ValerieParham-Thompson I'm getting `[initandlisten] exception in initAndListen std::exception: boost::filesystem::exists: Permission denied: "/path/that/iwant", terminating` and the `ls -ld` looks like `drwxrwxr-x 2 mongodb nogroup 4096 Apr 21 23:12`

Comment: The path is in my home folder, I'm not sure if that makes a difference...

Answer (score 1):

Firstly instead of installing mongodb through apt just get a tar or zip of it.

1)Extract it to your home folder or wherever you would like.

2)Mark the mongod,mongo,mongos executable.

3)make a conf file say mongod.conf and add

```
 dbpath=conf/data/db
 logpath=conf/log/mongod.log
 logappend=true
 port = 27001
 fork = true
```

4)Start mongod by

```
 path/bin/mongod --config path/mongod.conf
```

"bin" because you will find mongod in bin folder after extract

Comment: I'm not sure if you've noticed I have an [ARM](https://github.com/skrabban/mongo-nonx86) processor...